# Chart.js - compacting the chart and make the slope of lines being more abrupt

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am totally new to Chart.js and I am trying to do the following:

- I want the slope of lines to be more abrupt between data points.

What I thought it would be trivial, I found that it is a bit more complex than I thought.

Here is my current code, and the display of chart:

```
        // X Axis constant labels
        const labelsReading = ['2000', '2003', '2006', '2009', '2012', '2015', '2018', '2022'];

        // Y Axis constant labels
        const minYAxis = 370,
              maxYAxis = 570,
              stepYAxis = 20,
              tension = 0,
              cubicInterpolation = 'default',
              aspectRatio = 1.4,
              stackWeight = 2;

         const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: labelsReading, // labels
                        datasets: dataset // dataset
                    },
                    options: {
                        aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
                        cubicInterpolationMode: cubicInterpolation,
                        events: ['click'],
                        plugins: {
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Title' // title of the chart
                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                mode: 'index',
                                intersect: false
                            }
                        },
                        scales: {
                        x: {
                            grid: {
                                display: false, 
                                drawBorder: false 
                            }
                        },
                        y: {
                            stackWeight: stackWeight,
                            min: minYAxis,
                            max: maxYAxis,
                            ticks: {
                              stepSize: stepYAxis,
                            },
                            grid: {
                                display: false, 
                                drawBorder: false
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    }
                })
            );
        }
```

What I have tried:

- **aspectRatio**: This was the closed solution to my problem. The biggest
  drawback is that the chart is too big. I would like to stick with the
  default of 2, if possible.
- **stackWeight**: This didn't work as I expected. IT is true that my data is distributed in such way that it forms 2 group, and I thought
  having this set to 2 would indeed solve the problem, but the second
  group was out of the graph, and the emphasis was only on the first
  one. Not what I want.
- **maintainAspectRatio**: I tried to set this to false, in combination with aspectRatio, but it seemed that chart.js entered in
  some sort of while true loop which constantly zoomed in to my graph
  until crashed (dunno why).

Here is the version of chart.js I am using:

```
    <script src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js></script>
```

And here is an example of data:

```
    const data = [{
                label: "Netherlands",
                data: [
                    524.86151,
                    522.21814,
                    522.05585,
                    508.5748,
                    503.38382,
                    488.31683
                ],
                backgroundColor: netherlandBackgrondColor,
                borderColor: netherlandBorderColor,
                borderWidth: borderWidth,
                pointRadius: pointRadius,
                pointHoverRadius: pointHoverRadius,
                pointHitRadius: pointHitRadius
       }]
```

Here is how current rendering looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF0gQ.png

Here is what I would like to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIyvi.png

I hope I made myself understood !

Thanks for your time !

Comment: I think that what you want is to change the overall size of your chart (either reduce the width or increase the height). For that, you have to set `maintainAspectRatio: false` (which has the effect that the whole canvas is used) and set the CSS size of the div that contains the canvas, as described [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note) - this is a good approach even if the chart is not responsive.